# Queen vs rook & knight with all pawns

Tags: learning, theory, strategy, best-practice

I'm going through a chess tutorial (Shredder). One of the exercises begins where all pawns are in their starting positions. I have a queen and my opponent has a rook and a knight, again all in starting positions.

```
    [FEN "r5n1/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/3Q4 w - - 0 1"]
    [Title "Exercise - Capture all the pieces"]
```

I need to eliminate the opposing pieces or at least prevent them from moving. At the "hard" setting I can't even get close to succeeding.  Can anyone give me some clues, or things to consider as I try to "win" this?

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent them from moving"? That sounds like an impossible task...

Comment: If I get rid of the knight and rook, the pawns can be blocked.  At that point I don't have to capture those pawns.

Comment: *I have a queen and my opponent has a rook and a knight, again all in starting positions* Which rook? Which knight? This is important feature of the position, please edit your post with precise data. *I need to eliminate the opposing pieces or at least prevent them from moving.* This part is very unclear. Can we just assume the following: In starting position, White has all pawns and a queen, while Black has all pawns, rook and a knight -> How can White win? If not, please clarify this part.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff I have to wait till I get home to make sure the following is correct, but I'm pretty sure the positions are:  White Queen on D1.  Black - Rook on A8, knight on G8.  All 16 pawns in their starting positions.  White to move.  There are no kings, as this is an exercise, so "winning" is taking all Black pieces with the possible exception of a few being blocked.  That is, Black has no move after White's last turn.

Comment: @MitchellKaplan: This sounds more like a complex puzzle... The "blocking part" is the one that brings confusion. If you simply want to know how to win this position then I can whip up a fast answer. Taking all of Black's pieces is not necessary in order to win, so if this is a puzzle that forces you to take all of Black's pieces ( and tolerates if there will be some Black pieces left under condition they are blocked ) then that is another story...

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Thanks, but I'm trying to learn and was not making much progress.  So I wasn't looking (yet) for a solution, just some general principles or hints to help me better attack the problem.  For example bringing my queen out early or throwing everything behind promoting a pawn.  The way the computer plays I can't get my queen to Black's back rank early on because he keeps his Rook there for a while.  If I get rid of too many Black pawns, that frees up the Rook to cause damage.

Comment: @MitchellKaplan: Again, the part about "blocking" or removing all pieces confuses me. If you seek the win then the solution is simple. I could even post a game that can illustrate the winning principle if you are interested...

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Okay - I'm sure I'd benefit from seeing such a game.  Thanks!

Comment: @pablo how do you get that visual of the board?

Comment: Click on the "edit" button to see more, but essentially it's with [FEN ""]. Check [this](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/179/how-do-i-add-a-replayer-to-my-post) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Attack those pawns on side where is no rook. Once he makes a hole, get your queen on his backs. This way you will be able to grab like 2~ I'd say. Then run with a pawn on a free file.

`1. e3/e4 - Nc6 2. Qh5-h6 3. Qg4-g6 4. Qf4-h5 5. Qh6`
just an example